# In Angular2, how to get styles loaded before app display

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm working with Angular2, webpack, starting from https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

I use bootstrap 4 for styles. Bootstrap is configured with a .bootsraprc file and loaded with bootstrap-loader following this tutorial :https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-4-and-Sass-(and-jQuery)

My app.style.scss main entry for styles is called from .bootsraprc

So the problem is: When the app is included and ready, styles are not applied. It takes like a second for it to be done.

What is the best way to implement a loader that callback when the styles are loaded?

Comment: Is this during development or after you built using offline template compiler (AoT)?

Comment: During development, actually i still don't figure how to compile AOT

Comment: I wouldn't worry to much about development. With AOT this will look quite different. The rewriting of the styles that is done at runtime during development, will be done when you build so it doesn't need to be done when your application loads in production.

Comment: I can't help you with AOT. I'm using Dart and here build works quite different.

Comment: Thanks, Aot sounds like a solution

Comment: AoT will be your solution. The only other option available now would be to build a static stylesheet and send it before any Angular code is run. That's just not efficient for something that may never need the entire stylesheet.